# Collecting customer text info with a configurable product in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have several complicated configurable products in our store, with a series of 4 levels of attribute choices for each product. These work fine, but whenever somebody orders one of these configurable products, we need to collect some extra information from them in the form of a text input.

It doesn't matter to us whether we ask for the info on the product page, in the shopping cart or on the checkout page, as long as it's captured before the order is placed and it's easy for us to view on the admin.

Any recommendations on how best to achieve this?

Comment: create custom option Text type for configurable product.

Comment: Thanks Mufaddal. That seems to do the job we're after :) I can't think why we didn't do this before. Maybe it wasn't possible in a previous version so we discounted it as an option? Anyway, thanks. that does what we need.